# spring security 4.0.0 java configuration with no xml

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm trying to configure a spring security without any web.xml or xml at all, but I get an error which I can't get ride of. Do I get the error because of spring framework version? or the version is in conflict with spring security?

Here are the codes and error.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{


@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
{
    http.authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/signup", "/logout", "/login", "/default").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
    .antMatchers("/user/**").hasRole("USER")
    .anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and()
    .formLogin()
    .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
    .and()
    .logout()
    .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
    .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout=success")
    .logoutUrl("/logout");
}


@Bean
public BCryptPasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder()
{
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}


@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity builder) throws Exception
{
    builder.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**");
}

@Bean
public AuthenticationManager getAuthenticationManager() throws Exception
{
    return super.authenticationManager();
}
}
```

The initializer

```
public class SpringWebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer
{

private static final String DISPATCHER_SERVLET_NAME = "dispatcher";
private static final String DISPATCHER_SERVLET_MAPPING = "/";

// gets invoked automatically when application starts up
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException
{

    // Create ApplicationContext. I'm using the
    // AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext to avoid using beans xml files.
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    rootContext.register(WebMvcConfig.class);

    // Add the servlet mapping manually and make it initialize automatically
    Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet(DISPATCHER_SERVLET_NAME, new     DispatcherServlet(rootContext));
    dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    dispatcher.addMapping(DISPATCHER_SERVLET_MAPPING);

    EnumSet<DispatcherType> dispatcherTypes = EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST, DispatcherType.FORWARD);
    CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
    characterEncodingFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
    characterEncodingFilter.setForceEncoding(true);

    FilterRegistration.Dynamic characterEncoding = servletContext.addFilter("characterEncoding", characterEncodingFilter);
    characterEncoding.addMappingForUrlPatterns(dispatcherTypes, true, "/*");

    FilterRegistration.Dynamic security = servletContext.addFilter("springSecurityFilterChain", new DelegatingFilterProxy());
    security.addMappingForUrlPatterns(dispatcherTypes, true, "/*");


    //add HiddenHttpMethodFilter  filter
    //this will make sure that spring MVC works well with PUT/DELETE requests
    //made with a hidde _method field
    HiddenHttpMethodFilter hiddenHttpMethodFilter  = new HiddenHttpMethodFilter  ();
    FilterRegistration.Dynamic hiddenHttpMethod = servletContext.addFilter("hiddenHttpMethodFilter", hiddenHttpMethodFilter);
    hiddenHttpMethod.addMappingForUrlPatterns(dispatcherTypes, true, "/*");
    hiddenHttpMethod.setAsyncSupported(true);   
    servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

}

}
```

The error code:

```
 SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class    org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is     org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void     org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.setObjectPostProcessor(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor); nested    exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.lang.reflect.Parameter.isNamePresent()Z
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1202)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:762)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
at  org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4795)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5221)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
 Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method:  public void         org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.setObjectPostProcessor(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor); nested       exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.lang.reflect.Parameter.isNamePresent()Z
22 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.lang.reflect.Parameter.isNamePresent()Z
at   org.springframework.core.StandardReflectionParameterNameDiscoverer.getParameterNames(StandardReflectionParameterNameDiscoverer.java:42)
at org.springframework.core.PrioritizedParameterNameDiscoverer.getParameterNames(PrioritizedParameterNameDiscoverer.java:54)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:465)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1111)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1006)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1127)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1051)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:949)
at   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement    .inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:603)
    ... 24 more
```

thanks for all helps I can get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by changing the versions to spring 3.2.8 and security to 3.2.5

Answer (score 1):

> Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.lang.reflect.Parameter.isNamePresent()Z

Seems like you are trying to run a Java 8 app on a server that has a lower jdk version.

Specifically, [`Parameter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Parameter.html) was only introduced in Java 8.

Comment: Ok thanks for your comment but
I have the same project with xml and it's working. 
So with no xml it cause problem? Don't understand the logic here.
Can it behave different with different way of coding? or?

Answer (score 0):

Changing versions of libraries didn't solve problem in my case.

I've solved it by moving SecurityConfiguration from this definition:

```
@Bean
public SecurityConfiguration securityConfiguration() {
  return new SecurityConfiguration();
}
```

To:

```
context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
context.register(new Class<?>[]{AppContext.class, SecurityConfiguration.class});
```